# What is the purpose of using multiple bootstrap column sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap, and I understand how Bootstrap uses a 12-column grid. When I want to make utilize a Bootstrap grid, I traditionally do it like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I also understand that different column sizes are used for different screen sizes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I've seen a lot of people do something similar to this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Why use multiple column sizes? Will the browser detect which one is appropriate to use?

Comment: Its mobile up. So if you only need 1 size col-xs-6 is enough. If you want different sizes in different breakpointa you specify more. One example is having 2 cols as in your example in all breakpoints but mobile like: <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>

Comment: In @mindore's example "col-sm-6 col-xs-12" would accomplish the same thing since md and lg will inherit the sm setting. That would get you two column spanning the width of the element on tablets and above and would give you one column spanning the entire width on phones.

Answer (score 16):

There is absolutely no reason to have all three classes in this example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

It is effectively the same as this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap grid classes work on all sizes above the size specified, so applying `col-xs-6` will cause that element to also contain 6 columns on any larger screen sizes, like sm, md, etc. I'm guessing that whoever is including all three classes in the first example does not have a firm understanding of how the Bootstrap grid system works.

You only need to include multiple classes if you want the element to be a different size on different screen sizes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options and it says for xs only 'less than' 768 where as every other size is 'greater than or equal'. So does this behavior not apply for 'xs'?

Comment: "Bootstrap grid classes work on all sizes above the size specified, so applying col-xs-6 will cause that element to also contain 6 columns on any larger screen sizes, like sm, md, etc". Can you explain how? Does it use javascript to achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

Multiple `col` sizes are for different types of screens:

> - `xs`: Extra Small screens (phones)
> - `sm`: Screen like for tablets
> - `md`: Screen like Desktop
> - `lg`: Screen for larger desktops

Basically these will be defined in various `media` queries in `bootstrap.css` which helps browser to detect which one to use.

**[Learn more here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)**

---

**Addendum**

The use of different `col` classes mentioned above should be in the only situation where you are specifying different column sizes for different screens. For ex: if you want 12 `col` in `xs`, 6 `col` in `sm`, 3 `col` in `md` and 2 `col` in `lg`, then you can use it as `col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2`. Otherwise if they are going to be same for all the screens then you can use any one from above, as in `col-lg-6`. This will tell browser to use 6 `cols` irrespective of screen size.

Comment: Your addendum seems to be backwards or it's worded poorly. It implies that if you want to show 1 col in xs you should use col-xs-1 but col-xs-1 would make the content only take up one of the 12 columns. You have to use col-xs-12 if you want one visible column. I see no reason why you'd want to use your "col-xs-1 col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-12" example since it means the content will take up progressively more of the width as the screen gets larger. That's going to make annoyingly wide content on big screens and tiny content on little screens. "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3" would work better.

Comment: @SteveHiner.. Thanks for pointing out.. Updated the Addendum.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this page to get an idea

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

In general The idea behind using multiple col classes is to use different width percentages based on the screen size :

Example :

if u add a col-md-6 and a col-xs-12 on a element , when the screen size is near the medium breakpoint it will use 6 columns but when the screen size is small it would use the entire width

Answer (score -2):

The method is usually used for screen sizes. It is so you don't end up with 7 columns on a 7-inch screen. For example; with `<div class="col-xs-1 col-md-3 col-lg-6">` you can have 1 column on a phone, 3 columns on a large tablet and 6 columns on a desktop monitor.

Comment: This is totally wrong. Go look at http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ to understand the grid. "col-xs-1" means on phones you want the content to take up 1 of the 12 columns. "col-lg-6" means on large screens you want the content to take up half of the 12 columns. Your example would make the content get smaller on small screens and bigger on big screens which makes no sense. "col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-12" would make a lot more sense. As the size of screen goes down you want the content to progressively take up more columns so it will be bigger and easier to read.

Comment: I'm not sure how I made this mistake, a little embarrassing really. Probably had something to do with the four-in-the-morningness of it all. Thanks for the correction.